# mikrotik script is not run through GUI or Schedule

Tags: https, scripting, url, mikrotik, ddns

I get a problem that i have a one line script as bellow:

```
/tool fetch url="https://......"
```

When i run this script in winbox with "Run Script" button it does not work and after i put it in scheduler also it does not work ( The url is not called ).

The interesting thing is that when i go in terminal and run the script in terminal it calls the url and everything works as expected.

any help or idea will be helpful, Thanks ...